# How to get the roles associated to a report in iccube

Tags: iccube

I am  willing to list users their roles and the reports that are attached to every role, i could already list the users and their roles based on the files users and roles in iccube folder installation.

Is there any way to get the list of roles associeted to a report in iCcube?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the access rights associated to the reports (and any other files) through the Docs application in the icCube Web interface. Out of the box, the Docs repository is backup by the file system (see docsRepository in icCube.xml).